Titration of primary amine sulfate
I would like to know if there is any relatively “simple” method to determine a sample of primary amine sulfate mixed with a very weak base. For example, if pure amphetamine and caffeine were mixed, how could the proportion be determined?
I thought about the Kjeldahl method, but the other component caffeine contains nitrogen as well, which would likely make things complicated.
Then I thought that the sulfate salt is a weak acid and maybe it can be titrated with a strong base. Presumably caffeine would not interfere interfere significantly?

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155954/discussion-between-mithoron-and-pajaro-amarillo
